# Action Listener Paint Program: how to implement drawing a point, triangle, polygon, undo button, thickness, and fill?

Tags: java, swing

For a project, I have to implement the following processes into a paint program:

1. add a Point class to draw a Point
2. add a Triangle class to draw a Triangle (click on points and then connect them )
3. add a Polygon class to draw a Polygon
4. modify the code to make the thickness work
5. add the ability to fill an object
6. add an undo feature

My current program includes drawing ellipses, rectangles, and lines. I am able to choose a color from a swatch gradient, etc. I tried to do the point class as a ellipse with a width and height of 20 and nothing happens when I click the run screen. How can I fix my point class? I also do not know how to start the other classes. I've tried to find information but everything I've found doesn't use the Action Listener or uses terms I'm unfamiliar with.

Here is the main class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
    // the draw panel
    JPanel content;
    CustomPanel contentCustom;
    
    String filename = "";
    File file = null;
    
    // Menu Bar 
      JMenuBar bar;

    // file menu
    JMenu     fileMenu;
    JMenuItem openItem;
    JMenuItem saveItem;
    JMenuItem exitItem;
    //JMenuItem undoItem;
    
    // mode menu
    JMenu     modeMenu;
    JMenuItem lineItem;
    JMenuItem rectItem;
    JMenuItem ellipseItem;
    JMenuItem freeItem;
  JMenuItem pointItem;
    
    // color menu
    JMenu     colorMenu;
    JMenuItem colorItem;
    
    public Main()
    {
        super("Paint - Line Mode   Color="+Color.BLUE );
        setSize(800, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        // create the menu bar
        bar = new JMenuBar();
        
        // create the menus
        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        fileMenu.setMnemonic('F');    // Alt F 
        
        modeMenu = new JMenu("Mode");
        
        colorMenu = new JMenu("Color");

        // **** create the menu items
        // file menu items
        saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
        saveItem.setMnemonic('s');
        saveItem.addActionListener(this);

        openItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
        openItem.setMnemonic('o');
        openItem.addActionListener(this);

        exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        exitItem.setMnemonic('x');
        exitItem.addActionListener(this);

        /*undoItem = new JMenuItem("Undo");
        undoItem.setMnemonic('u');
        undoItem.addActionListener(this);
        */
        // mode menu items
        lineItem = new JMenuItem("Line");
        lineItem.addActionListener(this);
        
        rectItem = new JMenuItem("Rectangle");
        rectItem.addActionListener(this);
        
        ellipseItem = new JMenuItem("Ellipse");
        ellipseItem.addActionListener(this);
        
        pointItem = new JMenuItem("Point");
        pointItem.addActionListener(this);

        freeItem = new JMenuItem("Free Draw");
        freeItem.addActionListener(this);

        // color menu items
        colorItem = new JMenuItem("Color");
        colorItem.addActionListener(this);
        

        // **** add menu items to the menus
        // fileMenu
        fileMenu.add(openItem);
        fileMenu.add(saveItem);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(exitItem);
        //fileMenu.add(undoItem);
        
        // modeMenu
        modeMenu.add(lineItem);
        modeMenu.add(rectItem);
        modeMenu.add(ellipseItem);
        modeMenu.add(pointItem);
        modeMenu.add(freeItem);
        
        // colorMenu
        colorMenu.add(colorItem);

        // **** add the menus to the bar
        bar.add(fileMenu);
        bar.add(modeMenu);
        bar.add(colorMenu);
        
        // **** set the bar to be the menu bar
        setJMenuBar(bar);
        
        // Container content = getContentPane(); replace this with our own
        content = new CustomPanel();
        contentCustom = (CustomPanel) content;
        
        FlowLayout lay = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);
        content.setLayout(lay);
 
            setContentPane(content);
        setVisible(true); // always do this last
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      Object source = e.getSource();
      
      if (source == exitItem) 
      {
       System.exit(0);
      }
      else if (source == lineItem)
      {
        contentCustom.setMyMode("Line");
        setTitle("Paint - " + ((CustomPanel) content).getMyMode() + " Mode   Color="+
                  ((CustomPanel) content).getColor()
                );
      }
      else if (source == rectItem)
      {
        ((CustomPanel) content).setMyMode("Rectangle");
        setTitle("Paint - " + ((CustomPanel) content).getMyMode() + " Mode   Color="+
                  ((CustomPanel) content).getColor()
                );
      }
      else if (source == ellipseItem)
      {
        ((CustomPanel) content).setMyMode("Ellipse");
        setTitle("Paint - " + ((CustomPanel) content).getMyMode() + " Mode   Color="+
                  ((CustomPanel) content).getColor()
                );                                   
      }
     else if (source == pointItem)
      {
        contentCustom.setMyMode("Point");
        setTitle("Paint - " + ((CustomPanel) content).getMyMode() + " Mode   Color="+
                  ((CustomPanel) content).getColor()
                );
      } 
      else if (source == freeItem)
      {
        ((CustomPanel) content).setMyMode("Free");
        setTitle("Paint - " + ((CustomPanel) content).getMyMode() + " Mode   Color="+
                  ((CustomPanel) content).getColor()
                );
      }
      else if (source == colorItem)
      {
        Color  color = Color.black;
        Color newColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(this,"Draw Color",color);
        if (newColor != null)
          ((CustomPanel) content).setColor(newColor);
        setTitle("Paint - " + ((CustomPanel) content).getMyMode() + " Mode   Color="+
                  ((CustomPanel) content).getColor()
                );
      }
      else if (source == saveItem)
      {
        try
        {
          JFileChooser fileChooser = null;
          int result = JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION;
          
          if (filename.equals(""))
          {
            fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            result = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);              
          } 
          
          if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
          {
            if (filename.equals(""))
              {
              filename = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
              file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
              }
            // use contentCustom to reference the CustomPanel variables
            
            FileWriter fw=null;
            BufferedWriter bw=null;
            try
            {            
              fw = new FileWriter(file);
              bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            
              for (int j=0; j < contentCustom.myList.size(); j++)
              {
                AbstractShapeObject myShape =  contentCustom.myList.get(j);
                String outLine = myShape.toString();                               
                
                
                bw.write(outLine);
                bw.newLine();
              }
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
            }
            finally
            { 
              try
              {                    
                bw.close();
              }
              catch (Exception e2)
              {
              }
            }
          }
          else if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION)
          {
          }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
        }
        
      }
      /*else if (source == undoItem)
      {
        if (canUndo == true)
        {

        }
      }*/
      else if (source == openItem)
      {
        try
        {
          JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
          int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
          if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
          {
            file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

            if (file != null)            
            {
            filename = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
            contentCustom.myList.clear();


            FileReader fr=null;
            BufferedReader br=null;
            try
            {            
              fr = new FileReader(file);
              br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            
              String s = br.readLine();
              while (s != null)
              {
              
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s,",");
                
                String mode = st.nextToken();
                
                if (mode.equals("Line"))
                {
                    int x1 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int y1 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int x2 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int y2 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int red = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int green = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int blue = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    Color color = new Color(red,green,blue);
                    AbstractShapeObject myShape = new Line(x1,y1,x2,y2,color);
                    myShape.setMode("Line");
                    myShape.setKeep(true);                    
                    contentCustom.myList.add(myShape);                    
                }
                else if (mode.equals("Rectangle"))
                {
                    int x = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int y = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int width = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int height = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int red = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int green = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int blue = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    Color color = new Color(red,green,blue);
                    AbstractShapeObject myShape = new Rectangle(x,y,width,height,color);
                    myShape.setMode("Rectangle");
                    myShape.setKeep(true);
                    contentCustom.myList.add(myShape);                    
                }
                else if (mode.equals("Ellipse"))
                {
                    int x = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int y = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int width = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int height = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int red = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int green = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int blue = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    Color color = new Color(red,green,blue);
                    AbstractShapeObject myShape = new Ellipse(x,y,width,height,color);
                    myShape.setMode("Rectangle");
                    myShape.setKeep(true);
                    contentCustom.myList.add(myShape);                    
                }
                 else if (mode.equals("Point"))
                {
                    int x = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int y = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            
                    int red = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int green = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int blue = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    Color color = new Color(red,green,blue);
                    AbstractShapeObject myShape = new Ellipse(x,y,20,20,color);
                    myShape.setMode("Rectangle");
                    myShape.setKeep(true);
                    contentCustom.myList.add(myShape);                    
                }
              
                s = br.readLine();
              } // end of while loop
              
            contentCustom.repaint();
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
            }
            finally
            { 
              try
              {                    
                br.close();
              }
              catch (Exception e2)
              {
              }
            }
                
            }
          }
          else if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION)
          {
          }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
        }
        
      }
      
    }
    
  public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main paint = new Main();        
    }
    
    
} // end of class Main
```

Here is the point class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Point extends AbstractShapeObject {

    public Point(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        super(x,y);
    }
    
    public Point(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color) {
        super(x,y,color);// call the appropriate super constructor
        
    }

    public Point(int x, int y, int width, int height, int thickness) {
        super(x,y,thickness);// call the appropriate super constructor
        
    }

    public Point(int x, int y, int width, int height, int thickness, Color color) {
        super(x,y,thickness,color);// call the appropriate super constructor
        
    }

    public void draw(Graphics window)
    {
        // first, set your draw color
        
        window.setColor(getColor());// window.????(????);
        
        // second, draw the shape (i.e. draw the ellipse or Oval)
    
        window.fillOval(getX(),getY(),20,20);// window.????(????);
    }
    
    // write the toString() method
    // use the same format that is used for the Rectangle and Line classes
    public String toString()
    {
        return getMode() + "," + getX() + "," + getY() + ","  
                    + getColor().getRed() + "," + getColor().getGreen() + "," + getColor().getBlue();                 
    }
} // end of class Point
```

Comment: Firstly, in all of the [empty] `catch` blocks in your code, you should add a call to method `printStackTrace`, for example `e1.printStackTrace()`. You wrote in your question: _nothing happens when I click the run screen_ I don't know what you mean by _click the run screen_ but _nothing happens_ probably means you are getting an exception but since all your `catch` blocks are empty, you can't know for sure.

Comment: I mean that when I run the program and attempt to draw something, with my other shapes (the ellipses, lines, and rectangles), they show up fine. However, with the point, nothing happens when I try to draw but no errors are shown.